# Simple (easy to understand) definition of squarefree integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am first year Calculus student and have been reading a little bit about some basic number theory topics and I cannot seem to find square-free numbers to be defined in simple symbolic notation, ie. nothing more complicated then iff, implication, and, or, divides, does not divide. From the word definitions from wiki, I get the intuition behind it, but when it is written symbolically they use notations that are above my level of understanding. So I was wondering if someone could please, if it is possible to define square free numbers using the basic symbols stated above. I ask because when I read about the concept of m divides n and it was shown as m|n and this helped solidify my understanding.

Thanks

Comment: Try to choose a more fitting title for your question next time, e.g. "Definition of squarefree integers"

Comment: @Tomas Edit it yourself. It will earn you $2$ points. But you did good advising the OP.

Comment: Thank-you, good to know. I am probably pushing my luck, but I also cannot find any definitions of multiplying  square-free numbers together. My intuition says this would equal a square-free number as well. Is this true for all square-free numbers?

Comment: No, this is wrong. $2$ is squarefree, but $2\cdot 2$ not. Or if you want different integers, choose $10=2\cdot 5$ and $6=2\cdot 3$ and you see $2^2\mid 6\cdot 10 = 60$.

Comment: Is this why I do not find the product of square_free number in any textbooks?

Comment: Probably yes, since it has no special properties, it does not seem worth to mention.

Comment: @user84184: Well, technically there is some property of the product of two squarefree numbers - it is _cubefree_ ( i.e. $\forall p\in\mathbb P: p^3\nmid a$). But I don't think, that this is such an interesting concept ;-)

Answer (score 4):

$a\in\mathbb Z\backslash\{0\}$ is called *squarefree*, iff
$$\forall p\in\mathbb P: p\mid a \Rightarrow p^2 \nmid a$$
where $\mathbb P$ is the set of prime numbers.

**EDIT:** Or even simpler:
$$\forall p\in\mathbb P: p^2\nmid a$$

Comment: Why exclude $0$?

Comment: Well, _squarefreeness_ somehow concerns the factorization of integers. It just seems odd to ask, whether $0$ is squarefree. However, it would be well-defined and _not squarefree_ according to this definition, as everything divides zero.

Comment: Although squarefreeness does encode information about the prime factorization, I think your "simpler" way of stating it is much more elegant. With that definition, $0$ certainly is not squarefree, and this is what I would expect: squarefree numbers should not be very divisible in a certain sense, and $0$ is very divisible in every sense. Just a remark!

Comment: Alright, I get your idea as well. I think, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Last question, I promise, since my intuition failed me, could I prove this by taking the negation of the above definition modified by multiplying a*b, and then showing one of the examples above is why?

Comment: I'm not sure, whether I understand what you are asking. If $a$ and $b$ are squarefree, but $ab$ is not, then (thats the negation) $\exists p\in\mathbb P: p^2\mid ab$. But since $p^2\nmid a$ and $p^2\nmid b$, you get $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$. That's how the above example was constructed.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought, thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> Let $n \in \Bbb Z$. Then $n$ is **squarefree** iff:
>
> $$\forall m: m^2 \mid n \implies m^2 = 1$$

which translates to natural language as:

> "For each $m$, if $m^2$ divides $n$, then $m^2 = 1$."

---

Just for fun, we avoid the equality sign and the $1$:

> $$\forall m: m^2 \mid n \implies m^2 \mid m$$

However, since we're trying to define **squarefree**, it is unlikely that the squaring operation can be eliminated too.